# Android Studio Error while installing APK

Tags: android-studio

can someone please help me understand this error
I only have one phone connected, but for some reason it says offline under connected devices inside of Select Deployment Target. I have not been able to see the app on my phone either.

02/04 17:18:31: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\aaron\AndroidStudioProjects\HappyBirthday\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.happybirthday
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: more than one device
Error while Installing APK

Answer (score 0):

Clean and Rebuild your project then install